# Corrupt file getting generated when launching jupyter-pyspark kernel

Tags: linux, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

We have installed and setup jupyter notebook on two of our linux hadoop servers with pyspark kernels. Both the servers have same kernel.jason configuration which has same spark and pyhton versions.
on one server jupyter notebook ui --> pyspark kernel is working fine but on other server when launching pyspark kernel, a file(with name - ??????????) is getting generated in the users home directory, able to execute queries in opened pyspark kernel session, but when new jupyternotebook ui is launched and in corresponding pyspark kernel, unable to execute the queries. We are able to execute only after removing the ??????? file which was generated and relauching the jupyter notebook again.
-We see this behaviuor for all users, and is happening only on one server. Can someone please help out with in resolving this issue.
versions:
Python 2.7.12
Spark 2.1.1

Steps performed:

-Verified pyspark kernel configs with jupyter running on other server which has no issues.

-restarted spark client on the server

-Tried rebooting the server which did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can some please help with this issue, let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 0):

looks like might be an issue with the server hardware